# Convert DF into nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

**Problem**
I have a user log file in a dataframe (example data):

```
+------+--------+----------+------------+
| user |  prod  | prod_cat | goal_label |
+------+--------+----------+------------+
| a    | prod_1 | cat_1    |          5 |
| a    | prod_2 | cat_2    |          5 |
| c    | prod_1 | cat_1    |          1 |
+------+--------+----------+------------+
```

I'd like to get it (ultimately) into arrays (one entry per user):

```
[[[prod_1, cat_1], [prod_2, cat_2]],\
 [[prod_1, cat_1]]]
```

**Why I get lost**

```
unique_prod = prod_log.groupby(['user'])['prod'].unique()
unique_prod = unique_prod.to_frame().reset_index()
res = unique_prod['prod'].values
```

this works, but only for the column 'prod' - If I use the `unique` function on more than just the series it gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

So the question is:
Am I missing something obvious or does on of you masters have a neat solution? Or do I need to loop through?
Ultimately I'm trying to feed it into a LSTM network that needs the format of (sequence_length, input_dimension).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can approach this problem is to use a single series of lists, derived by zipping two input series:

```
df['prod_plus_cat'] = list(map(list, zip(df['prod'], df['prod_cat'])))

res = df.groupby('user')['prod_plus_cat'].apply(list).tolist()

print(res)

[[['prod_1', 'cat_1'], ['prod_2', 'cat_2']], [['prod_1', 'cat_1']]]
```

There are issues with your proposed method which mean it is unlikely to work:

- As you mention, no inclusion of `prod_cat` without performing an additional manipulation.
- `unique` should be used to return unique values, not group to a list.

Comment: You clearly answered the question and therefore earned the points. I don't think I can use it though... as I have lots more columns and around 1million rows... my computer struggles :) will look for a more efficient approach

Comment: @dv3, You might find the answer I posted separately more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *many* columns to aggregate across many rows, you can aggregate via taking the NumPy array representation and then casting to a list of lists.

Then use `GroupBy` + `apply` as normal:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['a', 'a', 'c'],
                   'prod': ['prod_1', 'prod_2', 'prod_1'],
                   'prod_cat': ['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_1'],
                   'sub_cat': ['sub_1', 'sub_2', 'sub_3'],
                   'goal_label': [5, 5, 1]})

df['comb'] = df[['prod', 'prod_cat', 'sub_cat']].values.tolist()

res = df.groupby('user')['comb'].apply(list).tolist()

print(res)

[[['prod_1', 'cat_1', 'sub_1'],
  ['prod_2', 'cat_2', 'sub_2']],
 [['prod_1', 'cat_1', 'sub_3']]]
```